# Iterate over json using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using using the Python requests library, to make a http request to some API that returns JSON.

```
   r = session.get('https://api.example.io/json')
   print(r.json()['data'][0]['Name'])
```

How do it iterate through all instances of ['Name'] ? I was only able to figure out how to specify an index.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "User1", 
            "age": 5
        }, 
        {
           "Name": "User2", 
            "age": 15
        }, 
        }, 
        {
           "Name": "User3", 
            "age": 55
        }, 
        .
        .
       }
    ], 
}
```

Comment: To get at the heart of your question, it can be rephrased as "how do I iterate over all values under a specific key in a list of dictionaries?" `requests` and JSON can be left out here.

Comment: did you tried: `names = [elm['Name'] for elm in r.json().get('data', [])]` ?

Answer (score 0):

The value with the key of 'data' is just a list of dicts. Can't you just use a for loop?

```py
for object in r.json()['data']:
     print(object['name'])
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, that worked :). And yes i'm a complete noob. Really appreciate the quick help on this.